# Android Search Dialog returns no results

Tags: android, sqlite, search, dialog

I am trying to following this tutorial:

http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-implementing-search-activities/

I've uploaded my code here: http://pastebin.com/9ik9m4n9

Order of files: SearchableActivity.java > search.xml > searchable.xml > DBHelper.java

When I hit the search button it pulls up the dialog but nothing will return when I type something. I think it is something wrong with retrieving data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("extra", "exttra info");
    // search initial query
    startSearch("Country", false, bundle, false);
    return true;
}
```